# Facebook login not working with extended permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

In my application, I have Facebook login functionality. It working fine in current application state. Due to new requirement I want add some extra permission while login with Facebook.

My problem: If user is logged in to Facebook from iOS Setting and already authorised to my Application, then with extended (newly added permissions) it Fails.

`FBSessionState` is `FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed`, Following is the error:

`Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x17842f30 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 7.)", com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x167846f0, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 6674573017, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x165b61d0>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}`

How should I handle this condition?

Comment: are you using the standard facebook SDK or some third party lib?

Comment: I am using SDK given by fecebook.

Comment: Please post your code on how you're requesting the permissions.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Facebook new SDK 3.15. Now app is always using Facebook app or Safari to Login.